# How to generate custom maven archetype with selected dependencies from the pom?

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

I am generating a custom archetype using maven. Currently I have three dependencies defined in the **pom.xml** (**dependency 1, dependency 2 and dependency 3**).

[image]

This is my **archetype-metadata.xml** file where I have defined the required properties for the archetype generation. Here I have a property called project-type which gets an input **1,2 or 3** and generate the project pom file with based on the entered input value

[image]

I just need the pom dependency to be generated based on the 'project-type' property. e.g. - **If the project type property is defined as 1, then the pom which generates with the archetype should have only the 'dependency 1'. If the value is 2, only dependency 2 should be included to the pom**

Can I do this ?
Or should I use 3 pom files here and use each file based on the value type ?
or any other ideal solutions to fix this ?

Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write if conditions within the pom.xml file based on the defined properties in the **archetype-metadata.xml** file. Since the name of the property is **project-type** in here, and then it will generated only the relevant dependencies in the generated archetype template

[image]